# Calculate topmost position of a CSS3 scaled box within another box

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, position, scale

This is a tricky one.

I need to find a way to calculate the correct position to align a box within another box at its top. However, there is CSS3 scaled content inside the inner box (the scale factor is known) so a basic based-on-top (0px) approach won't work.

As this is literally impossible to properly describe, see my jsFiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/gPyqS/a

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to have to get your math hands dirty here. The basic approach will be:

1. Get the offset of the element
2. Get the scale factor of the element
3. Get the height of the element
4. Get the Y component of the element's transformation origin
5. Consider a transform origin of -(box height / 2) to be `0`, and a transform origin of +(box height / 2) to be `1`. Given those constraints, perform linear interpolation using the current Y origin to determine the scale factor to apply to the top edge.
6. Multiply (box height / 2) by the value you derived in step 5, and subtract it from the Y offset you got in step 1. This is the visual offset of the top edge of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Specify transform-origin with the transform:

```
transform-origin: 0 0; 
-ms-transform-origin: 0 0; 
-webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;  
-moz-transform-origin: 0 0;  
-o-transform-origin: 0 0;
```

[Fiddle Update](http://jsfiddle.net/gPyqS/1/)

[W3C: transform-origin](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform-origin.asp)

Comment: That would be the perfect solution if only i could use it. The problem is that i need the origin to remain the center :/

Comment: The image i use in the box is part of a preview functionality for zooming an image. The zoom is animated (using CSS3 transform scale). If i change the transform-origin, zooming will no longer be center-based.